# Magento 1.9.3 : Show recently viewed product at homepage through block in rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, magento1.9.3

The problem in showing the recently viewed product.

How can I show it in homepage using the block? Like , I show new products through this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" products_count="2" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Is there any way to show the recently viewed product ?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755629/7545026

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
 Where I have to add this one

Comment: If you want to show this on home page then you don't need to use above code. You can use this code in your cms page

    {{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}

Comment: its not working. As I want to check the report.xml there is no report.xml

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `most-viewed.phtml` file in : `app/design/frontend/{packagename}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/most-viewed.phtml` then add this:

   ```
   $totalPerPage =4;
   $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
   $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->setStoreId($storeId)
                         ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                         ->addViewsCount()
                         ->setPageSize($totalPerPage);
   ?>
   <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); ?>
   <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #eaeaea; padding: 23px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <?php if ($_collectionSize) { ?>
       <h3 class="subtitle" style="background-color: #eaeaea; padding: 7px; color: #929292; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 15px;">Les plus vus block</h3>
       <ul class="products-grid">
           <?php
           foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
           <div class="col-md-3">
           <?php
               $image_url = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);
               $alt = $this->htmlEscape($this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true));
               ?>
               <li class="item">
                   <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                       <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo trim($alt)? $alt: $this->htmlEscape($this->stripTags($_product->getName())); ?>" />
                   </a>
                   <div class="product-info">
                       <h3 class="product-name">
                           <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                               <?php echo trim($alt)? $alt: $this->htmlEscape($this->stripTags($_product->getName())); ?>
                           </a>
                       </h3>
                   </div>
               </li>
           </div>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
       </ul>
   <?php } ?>
   </div>
   ```
2. add the piece of code bellow in your cms block:

   ```
   {{block type="core/template" name="most.viewed.block" template="catalog/product/most-viewed.phtml"}}
   ```

Comment: thank you for the code. But it is not working